# What's the difference between module and a module sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have three modules (standard module, not class module) in my Excel VBA project. One of those was added by right-clicking the VBAProject and insert a module. Two of them were added by executing "modules.add"; I guess modules means module sheets, right? So, my questions are:
1. What does a module mean in VBA?
2. How can I know which module is created while adding a modulesheet?
3. Why when I add a worksheet,there isn't a module appear?

Comment: This question is best suited for superuser.com?

Comment: [get your hands dirty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199701.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module is simply a place to put your code. You can just see it as a sheet of paper where you can write something.

In Excel you can put your code in a module, or "behind" a worksheet (what you call a modulesheet). A module is always added manually BY YOU. The "modulesheet" is part of a sheet and thus added or deleted BY EXCEL automatically whenever you create or remove a sheet

When you put some code and variables in a module, its instantly available from all worksheets within your workbook, dependinv on how you declare your variables, subs and functions (private/public)

Usually when one put code behind a worksheet, its because this code is only meant to be called from that particular worksheet and only perform operations on it.  I personnaly never work on worksheet level for several reasons:

- if you delete your sheet, you lose all code that was behind it.
- if you export a sheet, you export the code as well.
- if you duplicate a sheet, you duplicate the code as well.
- if you want to run the code behind a particular worksheet from another place, you have to fully qualify your calls and variables, which is a horrid solution and also plain boring

My advice is: IN EXCEL, never work on sheet level, uses modules, and if you reach a decent amount of code, organise it in logical groups using multiple modules

Answer (score 0):

RE 1: A module is like a singleton class which has already been initialized, so to speak. In other words a module's code (public properties/variables, public methods, etc) is always available, one does not have to inherit an instance before tries to use it, however, all the data in a module's properties/variables are common "application-wide"
RE 2: It is "sheet module", not "module sheet". This means nothing but the newly added sheet has a module with it when you add it. There's no difference between having this, or adding a module to the sheet later. You can open the code editor window and see modules, classes, etc by pressing ALT+F11
RE 3: By default no VBA code is added to any new sheet because of security reasons. If a Workbook has macro (VBA code) in it, extra attention is required so by default a workbook is not a VBA(macro) workbook.
Last but not least, please note that there's no difference between one module or another. The way you create a module does not affect the way modules behave, and there's only one "type of module" (as well as one "type of class module") in Office applications (Excel, Word, etc)

Comment: "Last but not least, please note that there's no difference between one module or another" That's not entirely true. If you add a module using the deprecated `modules.add` syntax, you actually get an Excel 5/95 module which is counted as part of the `Sheets` collection.

Answer (score 0):

for number 2:

```
Sub moduleAdd()
Modules.Add
'Modules.Add
qq = Modules.Count
MsgBox "total added module by code = " & qq

For ii = 1 To qq
Set modu = Modules(ii)
If ii = qq Then MsgBox "Newly added module = " & modu.Name
Next
End Sub
```